# java: is it more efficient a switch or a reflection?

Tags: java, performance, reflection, switch-statement

From a jsp I get a string that I could use for a switch

```
switch(value)
case 0: method0(); break;
case 1: method1(); break;
...
```

or for a reflection:

```
c.getMethod("method"+value, parameter);
...
```

Which approach is more efficient?

Comment: Reflection is always expensive to use. Only use it when there is no other way.

Comment: Have you tried microbenchmarking it? i.e. write the code and see! My initial guess would be the switch - note that it assumes more, generally if you assume more you can go faster!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflection is definitely not faster, as it has to go through additional layers.

However, using reflection for such a task would be the wrong way, as it makes the code harder to maintain and doesn't serve a real purpose which reflection is designed for.

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed number of methods and you are just *lazy* to type 1000 different `case`s, then you'd **definitely use `switch`**, because that statement is highly optimized on JVM bytecode level.

If you have an indefinite number of methods, you could **use *reflection*** (probably you don't have any other choices). Still you can speed up the process by *caching the `Method`* instances you get from `getMethod()`.

Note that passing arguments via reflection always creates extra arrays of `Class`es and `Object`s.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection has a big overhead if you're looking for quicker performance. According to the [Oracle Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

> Because reflection involves types that are dynamically resolved, certain Java virtual machine optimizations can not be performed. Consequently, reflective operations have slower performance than their non-reflective counterparts, and should be avoided in sections of code which are called frequently in performance-sensitive applications.

Java VM has special bytecodes which could be used for switch-case like `lookupswitch` and `tableswitch`.

The best approach if you are able to implement is *Polymorphism* , the Object Oriented approach.

Comment: Is there a way to use polymorphism if the only thing that I get (from my jsp) is a String that say to me which method I have to call?

Comment: Then use switch case , but I didn't get your design yet !

Comment: It's really simple, the user select a combo box and this return to me a single string id value, from this I've to call a different method for every id

Answer (score 1):

Reflection will always have some overheads

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

> Because reflection involves types that are dynamically resolved,
>   certain Java virtual machine optimizations can not be performed.
>   Consequently, reflective operations have slower performance than their
>   non-reflective counterparts, and should be avoided in sections of code
>   which are called frequently in performance-sensitive applications.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Switch**

> Reflection is powerful, but should not be used indiscriminately. If it is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it is preferable to avoid using it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Answer (score 0):

better to use switch option as reflection is heavy as compared to memory. and what if the case that is not available so that you can handle in switch statements while in reflection you have example of input * so it look for the method method* which is not available may be.

Comment: and switch statements often mean some kind of polymorphism, so use OO to rather than switch

Answer (score -1):

Basically first understand that when to use reflection ? it is mostly used for reflection to dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object. You can then invoke the type's methods or access its fields and properties.

But here you don't have such case so better to **use switch** instead of **reflection**.

And avoid unnecessary burden of your process.